# How to fill data in TCP packet

Tags: php, sockets, networking, tcp

Am developing client software to fill data in TCP packet and send to Server with given IP and Port. Server developer once told me I have to fill packet not create new one.

I have document from server developer that show how to format packet data and send via TCP transmission they said the packet command contain two parts, packet HEADER and BODY, this is my first time doing this kind of coding please help me on how I can code in PHP so as server can understand HEADER and BODY of my packet.

Sorry if my explanation is not clear let me know so as I can explain more

Comment: if you can develop you client in java instad of php I recommend you use Netty framework for java.

Comment: Thanks @Hector, I would like to do this in PHP now because I see on the Web that PHP now is mature enough for Client-Server programming if am not wrong. Let us see what others get to help.